# Segfaulting on deletion of a node in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

So what seems to be happening is that my program is not recognizing when a node is set to nullptr...I have no idea why this is.  Whenever I check for `if(node != nullptr)` it seems to pass and go right down into the statement.  I may be wrong in saying this, but this is what I think is happening...maybe you may come to a different conclusion.  Below is all of the code you should need, please let me know if you need me to post more in order to find the problem.

Thanks for any help ahead of time.

### Here's my code

```
void UseList::deleteNode(std::pair <unsigned, unsigned> data){
node *pre = nullptr, *del = nullptr;

// Check if its the head, if so then delete and update it
if(head->data == data){
    del = head;
    head = del->next;
    delete del;
    return;
}

pre = head;
del = head->next;

while(del != nullptr) { // <----- On the first execution, head is nullptr, so head->next should also be nullptr.  This line should not be allowing the program to descend into the code.
    if(del->data == data){ //   <----- Seg fault occurs here.
        pre->next = del->next;
        if(del = tail)
            tail = pre;
        delete del;
        break;
    }
    pre = del;
    del = del->next;
}
}
```

### Here's a GDB log of where its seg faulting

NOTE: The list is EMPTY when this delete is called. It should be recognizing that head->next is a nullptr and not trying to compare its data with the data to be deleted.

```
50              while(del != nullptr) {
(gdb)
51                      if(del->data == data){
(gdb)
std::operator==<unsigned int, unsigned int> (__x=..., __y=...)
at c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:215
215         { return __x.first == __y.first && __x.second == __y.second; }
(gdb)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00406352 in std::operator==<unsigned int, unsigned int> (__x=..., __y=...)
at c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:215
215         { return __x.first == __y.first && __x.second == __y.second; }
(gdb)
```

### Node Class Definition & Constructor

```
class node {
        public:
            std::pair <unsigned, unsigned> data;
            node *next;
            node *prev;
            node(){
                next = nullptr;
                prev = nullptr;
            }
            ~node(){
                delete next;
            }
    };
```

### List Constructor

```
UseList::UseList(){
head = tail = nullptr;
head->next = head->prev = nullptr;
tail->next = tail->prev = nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's caused by a typo.

You wrote:

```
   if(del = tail)
        tail = pre;
```

You probably meant:

```
   if(del == tail)
        tail = pre;
```

**Problems that I see**

1. This might not be your problem, but it's worth pointing out. You have:

   ```
   if(head->data == data){
   ```

   This will be a problem if the list is empty, i.e. `head == nullptr`.
2. The code in the constructor is not right. You have:

   ```
   UseList::UseList(){
     head = tail = nullptr;

     head->next = head->prev = nullptr;
     // Since head is nullptr, head->next and head->prev should
     // produce run time errors.

     tail->next = tail->prev = nullptr;
     // Same thing here also.
   }
   ```
3. The `while` loop in `deleteNode` needs careful walk through to make sure that you are doing the right thing.

   You have:

   ```
   if(del->data == data){
     pre->next = del->next;
     if(del = tail)
       tail = pre;
     delete del;
     break;
   }
   ```

   Let's say you have 25 items in your list and the given data is the 5-th item in the list. At that time, `pre` points to the 4-th node, `del` points to the 5-th node. Then you execute:

   ```
   pre->next = del->next; // This is good.
   ```

   Then you execute:

   ```
     if(del = tail)
   ```

   This statement points `del` to the tail of the list -- the 25-th node. The expression `(del = tail)` evaluates to `true. So, you execute:

   ```
     tail = pre;
   ```

Now `tail` points to the 4-th node in the list.

Then you execute:

```
      delete del;
```

which deletes the 25-th node of the list.

Now, the list is a strange state. `tail` points to the 4-th node. The 25-th node has been deleted but the 24-th node still points to it.

Comment: I did mean that, thank you. I've made the correction.  However, the seg fault is happening before the program reaches that line.

Comment: I've edited my deleteNode code to indicate the location of the seg fault.

Comment: @Riptyde4 I updated my answer pointing out the problems that I see.

Answer (score 1):

If `head` is `nullptr`, you cannot access `head->next`.

So error in this line:

```
del = head->next; // if head is nullptr
```

Maybe you could write it differently for the case where `head` is `nullptr`.